# Python AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode' in hashlib.encode

Tags: python, object, md5, encode

My code:

```
    for chars in chain(ALC, product(ALC, repeat=2), product(ALC, repeat=3)):
    a = hashlib.md5()
    a.update(chars.encode('utf-8'))
    print(''.join(chars))
    print(a.hexdigest())
```

It throws back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pyCrack.py", line 18, in <module>
a.update(chars.encode('utf-8'))
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Full output: http://pastebin.com/p1rEcn9H
It appears to throw the error after tring to move on to "aa".
How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: How about showing us what/where `chain()` is?

Comment: "from itertools import chain, product"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are `chain`ing heterogeneous types together, which is a certain cause of headaches.

Presumably `ALC` is a string, so `chain` first yields all the characters from the string.  When it moves on to `product(ALC, repeat=2)`, it starts yielding `tuple`s, since that's how `product` works.

Just yield homogeneous types from your `chain` call (i.e. always yield tuples, `join`ing them when you need a string) and the headaches disappear.

```
for chars in chain(*[product(ALC, repeat=n) for n in range(1,4)]):
    ...
    a.update(''.join(chars).encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score -1):

Your error is trying to convert this tuple to utf-8. Try remove this line "a.update(chars.encode('utf-8')"

When the interpreter shows "'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode' means that the object tuple does not support convert that way.

But, if you would like to convert all these things, use #coding: utf-8 in the first line of your program.

Comment: You can't encode a tuple because a tuple can't be converted into an encoding

Comment: I need to keep the "a.update(xxxxx)" as that is my replay to hashlib

Comment: @mnunberg I just suggest this way, enconding all code to 'utf-8', but it's true that tuple can't be converted.

But I question myself what's the propose to convert a tuple to 'utf-8'.